# How to specify a command when posting a form, using php?

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to post a form with php, and I want the form to be handled depending on the value of cmd. Specifying this after the filename does not work..what is the correct way to do this?

```
echo "<form name=\"statusForm\" action=\"edit_status.php?cmd=submitinfo\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">
```

Where/how can I specify ?cmd=submitinfo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "<form name=\"statusForm\" action=\"edit_status.php\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"cmd\" value=\"submitinfo\"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your form method is POST, and so you could probably just as easily do what you want with a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="submitinfo" />
```

Then just use the `$_POST` variable, as with your other form parameters, on the edit status page.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are getting at here. You should be able to get to the query string (the part after the ?cmd=) very easily. You are trying to access it from the edit_status.php file?

Secondly you are using ?_GET["cmd"]